# biber and biblatex incompatible versions

Tags: latex, bibtex, biblatex, texmaker

I'm using Texmaker and the configuration PDFLatex > Bib(la)tex > 2x PDFLatex > View PDF for Quick Build.

But after compiling I get the following error:

> INFO - This is Biber 2.17 INFO - Logfile is 'paper.blg' INFO -
> Reading 'paper.bcf' ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file
> version 3.7, expected version 3.8. This means that your biber (2.17)
> and biblatex (3.15a) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in
> biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

I checked the biber docs pdf and the latest compatible versions are Biber version 2.17 and Biblatex version 3.17.

Using MiKTeX Console I updated both (see images below) but TexMaker doesn't seem to care...

Any ideas on how to get it to compile it correctly?

[image: biblatex package information]
[image: biber package information]

EDIT: As requested the content of the .log-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.4.16)  17 APR 2022 07:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./paper.tex
(paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ieeetran\IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen138
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen139
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen140
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count185
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count186
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count187
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks16
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 5
03.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen141
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen142
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen143
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen145
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen146
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen147
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen148
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen149
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen150
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen151
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen152
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen153
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen154
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen155
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count195
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count196
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count197
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen156
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen157
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen158
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen159
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count198
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box50
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen160
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen161
\c@IEEEbiography=\count199
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box51
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cite\cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27  v 5.5
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen162
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen163
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count267
\leftroot@=\count268
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count269
\DOTSCASE@=\count270
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen164
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count271
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count272
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count273
\dspbrk@lvl=\count274
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count275
\column@=\count276
\maxfields@=\count277
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen165
\alignsep@=\dimen166
\tagshift@=\dimen167
\tagwidth@=\dimen168
\totwidth@=\dimen169
\lineht@=\dimen170
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/algorithms\algorithmic.sty
Package: algorithmic 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
\c@ALC@unique=\count278
\c@ALC@line=\count279
\c@ALC@rem=\count280
\c@ALC@depth=\count281
\ALC@tlm=\skip53
\algorithmicindent=\skip54
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen171
\Gin@req@width=\dimen172
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-04-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count282
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
)
(paper.aux)
\openout1 = `paper.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.

-- Lines per column: 56 (exact).
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count283
\scratchdimen=\dimen173
\scratchbox=\box55
\nofMPsegments=\count284
\nofMParguments=\count285
\everyMPshowfont=\toks23
\MPscratchCnt=\count286
\MPscratchDim=\dimen174
\MPnumerator=\count287
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count288
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks24
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 26.


(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 26.


(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ref1' on page 1 undefined on input line 48.

(paper.bbl)

** Conference Paper **
Before submitting the final camera ready copy, remember to:

 1. Manually equalize the lengths of two columns on the last page
 of your paper;

 2. Ensure that any PostScript and/or PDF output post-processing
 uses only Type 1 fonts and that every step in the generation
 process uses the appropriate paper size.

[1{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}



]
(paper.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4160 strings out of 478541
 65167 string characters out of 2849516
 361035 words of memory out of 3000000
 22347 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 507238 words of font info for 100 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,8n,62p,288b,266s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/Program Files/Mi
KTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/ty
pe1/urw/times/utmbi8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/ut
mr8a.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on paper.pdf (1 page, 56334 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

EDIT 2: After changing `biber %` to `bibtex %` in the Commands Settings of Texmaker (I changed it based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451963/error-can-not-find-control-file-bcf)), the minimal working example looks like this (eventhough the references are still empty...):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{to-do}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{to-do} \\
\textit{to-do}\\
to-do\\
to-do}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
Please observe the conference page limits. \cite{ref1}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

The output pdf looks like this:
[image: output pdf]

Comment: Can you show your .log file? Maybe you have a local version of biblatex lying around which is interfering.

Comment: (also try to delete all auxiliary files and compile again)

Comment: After deleting all auxilary files, I get the error `Cannot find 'paper.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1`

Comment: There does not seem any evidence in the log file that biblatex is loaded. Can you make a [mre] so we can check if the code is correct?

Comment: After changing from biber to bibtex in the settings the references were still empty. The entry in my .bib file had the wrong format. Correcting it, yielded a correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing from biber to bibtex in the Texmaker settings, the references were still empty.
**The entry in my .bib file had the wrong format**.
 Correcting it yielded a correct output.